# How to convert UnManaged to Managed List in Realm. I am using Kotlin with MVVM for Android

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, realm

I am using `RealmRecyclerViewAdapter` where I need to use managed list. 
Does anyone has idea how to convert unmanaged to managed list ?

As I am facing following error when converting unmanaged list to managed

> Error : Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only use this
>   adapter with managed RealmCollection, for un-managed lists you can
>   just use the BaseRecyclerViewAdapter

This is My Adapter Class

```
class ChannelVideosAdapter(var list: OrderedRealmCollection<RealmMediaListModel>?) : RealmRecyclerViewAdapter<RealmMediaListModel, ChannelVideosAdapter.ChannelVideos>(list,true) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone has idea how to convert unmanaged to managed list ?

You need to obtain either a `RealmResults` from a `Realm` instance, or a `RealmList` from a ***managed*** RealmObject (retrieved from a `Realm` instance or a `RealmResults`).

There is no way to convert an unmanaged list to a managed list.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `RealmRecyclerViewAdapter` you need to pass a managed RealmList or RealmResults.

If you want to use a unmanaged list, use a simple `RecyclerViewAdapter`.

`RealmRecyclerViewAdapter` has only some methods to react when the list/result changes, but can't happen with an unmanaged list/result.